# Failing to pass argument to component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am thinking from the error Expo gives me and from what I've read of others with similar problems that my syntax is wrong for passing parameters to the component `StudentScreen`. I am trying to make a Drawer, `StudentsScreen`, to list student names and when a student is selected, the app will display `StudentScreen` to show their information.

Error given: Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'Student1'. It must be a vilid React Component.

Here are the two components I have narrowed it down to. If there is anything I have left out, please let me know.

```
function StudentScreen({ studentName }) {
    const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
    const theName = studentName;

    return (
        <View>
          <Text>The student's name is {theName}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

function StudentsScreen({ navigation }) {
    const dimensions = useWindowDimensions();

    return (
        <StudentListDrawer.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                drawerType: dimensions.width >= 768 ? 'permanent' : 'slide',
            }}>
          <StudentListDrawer.Screen
            name='Student1'
            component={StudentScreen({studentName: 'Julia'})}
          />
          <StudentListDrawer.Screen
            name='Student2'
            component={StudentScreen({studentName: 'Samuel'})}
          />
        {/*
          <Text style={styles.headingText}> Home Screen </Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.userText}
                placeholder='Please add text'
                value={name}
                onChangeText={(text)=> setName(text)} />
          <Button
            title='Go to detail'
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate(
                "DetailScreen",
                { params:
                  { student: name }
                }
            )}
          />
         */}
        </StudentListDrawer.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Comment: I may have found a possible answer. I would still appreciate your wisdom if you don't mind, though, I am currently trying to see if this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator) will help me fix my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `component` prop of a screen in `any navigator including the Drawer` is just a reference to the actual JSX component in [react-native-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/).

**We usually do not create the actual component ourselves and pass it to the above prop. We just need to provide the imported reference**.

There are two ways to solve this problem.

1. Create an anonymous function

```js
 <StudentListDrawer.Screen
    name='Student1'
    component={() => <StudentScreen studentName="Julia" />}
 />
```

2. Use the `initialParams` prop and access it via the `route` object

```js
 <StudentListDrawer.Screen
    name='Student1'
    initialParams={{ studentName: 'Julia' }}
    component={StudentScreen}
 />
```

Access it via the `route` object as follows.

```js
function StudentScreen({ studentName, route }) {
    const [name, setName] = React.useState(route.params.studentName);

    return (
        <View>
          <Text>{`The student's name is ${name}`}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

**Remarks:** This works for every navigator, not just a Drawer.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I think I am going to go with the second option because it feels like it fits the way I think better.

The end goal is to have a variable number of student listings based on a connected data base (still a ways away from this). My gut also tells me the second one will make that easier, but I do not know enough about it yet to feel confident in that assessment.

Thanks again for helping to clarify that for me. Going to go get this fixed now.

Comment: So I believe I've set it up correctly how you suggested. I am now getting getting a mix of "invalid value for 'component' prop" or "navigator can only accept 'Screen', 'Group', or 'React.Component'. Is it a problem with the parameters not lining up? Should I add a route to the `initialParams`, or is the `name='Student1' the route?

Comment: I tried the first way also (see end of comment). I tried commenting out the initialParams and it says my ending } is an "Unexpected token". Without the comments, It gives the error about Navigators only accepting screens, groups, etc.

```
          <StudentListDrawer.Screen
            name='Student2'
            {/* initialParams={{ studentName: 'Samuel' }} */}
            component ={() => <StudentScreen studentName = "Samuel" />}
          />
```

Comment: [Here is a minimal snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/react-navigation---drawer-navigation-example) showcasing the above cases. It is based on the official drawer example. As you can see in this example, both suggested methods work as expected.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much David. It will definitely be helpful to reference the snack. I noticed when I reviewed my code today that apparently I had changed the `<View> // content </View>` in `StudentScreen` to another navigator. I do not remember doing it, but once I fixed it, both of your suggestions worked as expected. I will mark this as being solved. Thank you so much again.